# Difference between "dim a" and "dim a,b"

Tags: vba

Strange behaviour of VBA:

This gives an error 94 "Illegal use of Null" in line 3:

```
Function test1()
  Dim a As String
  a = Null
  test1 = a
End Function
```

BUT... this works perfectly:

```
Function test1()
  Dim a, b As String
  a = Null
  test1 = a
End Function
```

Only difference is the variable b in line 2, which is never used! WTF is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second code sample ...

```vb
Dim a, b As String
```

`As String` applies to only the last variable, *b*.  Variable *a* is Variant type.

A Variant variable can accept Null. A String variable can not.

In the first code sample, *a* is explicitly declared as String.  That is why it will not accept a Null.

If you want both *a* and *b* to be String type, you must explicitly declare the type for each ...

```vb
Dim a As String, b As String
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very disturbing for programmers that are new to VBA. So I think the correct syntax for this would be:
    Dim a as String, b as String
(If you do not want to use null)

Comment: Yes, I added that note to the answer.